# Problem of data recovery from a web API with javascript REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem to recover some data from a Web API in React.
Here is the url of the API: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/, which I stored in a state named pokeData.

When I try to **console.log(pokeData)**, it works very well. When I try to **console.log(pokeData.types)** always no problem ! BBut if I try to go further in the request with **console.log(pokeData.types[0])**, this message is displayed: "**TypeError: pokeData.types is undefined**".

```
const [pokeData, setPokeData] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeId}/`)
    .then((result, err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          setPokeData(result.data) 
        }
    })  
  },[pokeId]);


console.log( pokeData.types)

===> works very well 

console.log( pokeData.types[0])

===> "TypeError: pokeData.types is undefined"
```

I'm sure the solution should be simple, but I'm stuck... If someone could help me it would be great!

thanks :)

Comment: You're trying to access the data before it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a code sandbox for you https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-browser-0s8xu?file=/src/App.js:0-726

here is the code as well:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const pokeId = 1;
  const [pokeData, setPokeData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokeId}/`)
      .then((result, err) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          setPokeData(result.data);
        }
      });
  }, [pokeId]);
  console.log(pokeData);
  console.log(pokeData.types && pokeData.types[0]);
  console.log(pokeData.types && pokeData.types[1]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I believe the issue is the pokeData.types is not immediately available so you must wait for pokeData.types to be true by using the && operator

Comment: Thank you so much for your great answer! it helped me a lot.